# How to open multiple links/url using Autohotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

How do you open multiple links/url using Autohotkey?

The links/urls are one on each line.

The script should work without have to save the file. You select all the links and pressing the hotkey will open all the links.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script binds the key combination <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> to the function you want:

```
^!c::
  oCB := ClipboardAll
  Send ^c
  Loop,parse,clipboard,`n,`r 
  {
    Run %A_LoopField%
  }
  ClipBoard := %oCB%
```